# Sum timedeltas in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have multiple sets of dates/times I'm trying to manipulate in python, imported from a csv file using the pandas module. I've converted each entry from a string to datetime, and I can manipulate the data with + and -, but I get an error when trying to use 'sum()'. Specifically: "TypeError: 'Timedelta' object is not iterable".

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

A = pd.read_csv('filename')
B = A['Start Time (UTCG)']
C = A['Stop Time (UTCG)'] 


DT_B =  pd.to_datetime(B) #converting from string 
DT_C =  pd.to_datetime(C) 
timediff = DT_C - DT_B
diffsum = sum(timediff)
```

where 'Start time' and 'Stop time' are in the format "11 Mar 2017 10:37:12.330" and B and C are lists.

I'm pretty new to python, so apologies if I'm overlooking something simple. If there's an easier way to manipulate strings of dates/times without datetime, that would be good too. Any help in getting "sum" to work would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using the `sum` method that ships with a pandas series which should handle this correctly.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> data = [timedelta(i) for i in range(10)]
>>> a = pd.Series(data)
>>> a.sum()
Timedelta('45 days 00:00:00')
```

Note that I say `Series` and not dataframe. When you pull the exact column out of the dataframe as you did like this `C = A['Stop Time (UTCG)']` the type of `C` is a `Series`.

It might be cleaner to just create a new column from the other two in the first data frame, and then just aggregate or call the sum method on that column. Something like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> data1 = [datetime.now() for i in range(5)]
>>> data2 = [datetime.now() for i in range(5)]
>>> data = {'start': data1, 'stop': data2}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
                       start                       stop
0 2017-03-11 22:38:11.606500 2017-03-11 22:38:37.474962
1 2017-03-11 22:38:11.606509 2017-03-11 22:38:37.474971
2 2017-03-11 22:38:11.606510 2017-03-11 22:38:37.474973
3 2017-03-11 22:38:11.606511 2017-03-11 22:38:37.474974
4 2017-03-11 22:38:11.606512 2017-03-11 22:38:37.474975
>>> df.dtypes  // use dtypes to make sure the types are what you think they are
start    datetime64[ns]
stop     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
>>> df['diff'] = df['stop'] - df['start']
>>> df['diff'].sum()
Timedelta('0 days 00:02:09.342313')
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion with pd.series will work for my purposes.

Comment: @DCips Please mark my answer as correct if I answered your question :)